# python write cell to matrix in wrong way

Tags: python

I have a simple code for testing, my code supposed to only write matrix at (1,1) and (2,2), these two cells.

```
grid = [
[1,1,1,2,],
[1,9,1,2,],
[1,8,9,2,],
[1,2,3,4,]
]

n = 4   
duplicate = [[0]*n]*n

for i in range(1,n-1):
    for j in range(1,n-1):
        cur = grid[i][j]
        if (cur > grid[i-1][j]) and (cur > grid[i][j-1]) and (cur > grid[i+1][j]) and (cur > grid[i][j+1]):
            print(i,j)
            duplicate[i][j]="X"


print(duplicate)
```

My output:

```
1 1
2 2
[[0, 'X', 'X', 0], [0, 'X', 'X', 0], [0, 'X', 'X', 0], [0, 'X', 'X', 0]]
```

However, the output is supposed to be like this:

```
1 1
2 2
[[0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 'X', 0, 0], [0, 0, 'X', 0], [0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

What is wrong with my code?
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usual mistake: `[[0]*n]*n` creates a list of `n` references to the same list `[0]*n`. You need do this to create `n` different lists: `[[0]*n for _ in range(n)]` so you can update each one of them independently.

Comment: It works. Thanks a lot! I was struggling with this for half hour. You save me.

Answer (score 0):

The list your create use [[0]*n]*n is the same, You can prove by

```
duplicate = [[0]*4]*4
duplicate[1][1] = 1
```

You may understand more by look at this problem

```
def extendList(val, list=[]):
    list.append(val)
    return list

list1 = extendList(10)
list2 = extendList(123,[])
list3 = extendList('a')

print "list1 = %s" % list1
print "list2 = %s" % list2
print "list3 = %s" % list3

list1 = [10, 'a']
list2 = [123]
list3 = [10, 'a']
```

Comment: Hi Aison,  your program makes me confusing. 'code' list1 = extendList(10), why you only give one parameters, it should have two? Also, we don't input 'a' into list1, but why we get list1 = [10, 'a']? It is interesting. Thank you so much for your replying.

Comment: you can use id(list1) to check the list address. you may have a look at how python list implement http://www.laurentluce.com/posts/python-list-implementation/